# How can I create an unbuffered I/O multiplexer in Python?

Tags: python, io, unbuffered

I want a console python script that will receive input on stdin and immediately write it out to stdout and stderr simultaneously. This should be unbuffered both on input and output.

How would I do this? I assume it's pretty basic, once you know the trick.

Answer (score 1):

look at this

[Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering)